# Integrate Artifactory into Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am trying to integrate Artifactory into my Jenkins pipeline in order to push Maven artifacts to Artifactory.

My current understanding is, that I should deploy the built Maven artifacts with using the Jenkins pipeline rather than through a Maven plugin during the `deploy` lifecycle of Maven.

Based on the documentation that I have read so far I think I need code similar to this in my pipeline:

```
stage('Build') {
  steps {
    /** Start a docker container with maven and run mvn clean install */
  }
}

stage ('Deploy to Artifactory') {
  steps {
    script {
      def server = Artifactory.server 'my-server-id'

      def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()

      rtMaven.deployer.addProperty("status", "in-qa")
      buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'clean install'
      server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
    }
  }
}
```

However, I fail to completely understand what this is doing and I am unable to find more detailed documentation, execept for [this JFrog blog entry](https://jfrog.com/blog/dont-let-maven-deploy-plugin-trip-you/) and [this JFrog Confluence page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins).

In particular it seems that if I specify goals to the run directive it will run the Maven Pipeline again, which would not make much since the pipeline already ran in the first stage (e.g. 'Build').

In addition I should note, that I am running the maven build inside a docker container, so it seems that using the above setup is not quite enough for me.

Is there a best practice to approach this?

What I am looking for is a way to collect the artifacts that I built with maven in my docker container and upload them to Artifactory without running maven again.

Comment: Can you please clearly what you mean by"running maven again"? In the sample pipeline code you shared, maven is executed only once, by the "rtMaven.run" method.

Comment: In the first stage (e.g. 'Build'), I am running a full `mvn clean install` cycle inside an openjdk docker container. Once that stage is finished, I will have the built results in the local maven registry. Now when the 'Deploy' step starts, I do not want to start a full build with maven again, but I only want to take the existing mvn artifacts from my local `.m2/` folder and upload them to Artifactory.